# How to remove columns from an Excel file with xslt?

Tags: python, xlwt

I am working on a python function that generates a rather large and complex Excel file.

Once the file has been completely "written", I would like to be able to remove certain columns known beforehand (ex. columns 'B', 'E' and 'J') and then move the rest of the columns to the left leaving no empty column.

Is there any way to remove columns with `xlwt`? And to "move" them to the left?

Comment: Just to make things clear: you want to read an `xls` file, remove and move some columns and then save the file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: It's probably a better solution to simply not write that data in the first place, than to go in and filter it out later. Is that not possible for some reason?

Comment: Some users have to have access to the full version of that file. Others can only see some columns of that file.

As I said, it is a very large and complex file, so I think that just removing a few specific columns from the complete version would be less messy than modifying the code that generates the file, which is already very messy and complex.

Comment: Try using [``xlutils.filter.ColumnTrimmer``](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/filter.html#columntrimmer).